# How to redirect console output into a file in VxWorks shell?

Tags: vxworks

In Windows or Linux, it's very often we redirect console output to a file as below:

Windows:

```
dir > text
```

Linux:

```
ls -l > text
```

I wonder how to do the similar thing in VxWorks shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed "0x102" in "saveFd = open("myfile.txt",0x102, 0777 )" into "0x202", then it works. All console display was redirected into "myfile.txt".
In previous post, I got a mistake. I thought it hung after "ioGlobalStdSet(1, saveFd)". It's not hung, but redirecting all display into "myfile.txt" and I used "CTL-C" to stop the redirection.

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this:

```
-> saveFd = open("myfile.txt",0x102, 0777 )
-> oldFd = ioGlobalStdGet(1)
-> ioGlobalStdSet(1, saveFd)
-> runmytest()
...
-> ioGlobalStdSet(1, oldFd)
```

This will redirect all code to the file that you have opened, this case myfile.txt

Comment: I tried twice and it doesn't work. After I keyed in line of "ioGlobalStdSet(1,saveFd)
", it hung over there. How come? What's wrong with it?


-> saveFd = open("myfile.txt", 0x102, 0777)

new symbol "saveFd" added to symbol table.

saveFd = 0x5d52f18: value = -1 = 0xffffffff = saveFd + 0xfa2ad0e7

-> oldFd = ioGlobalStdGet(1)

new symbol "oldFd" added to symbol table.

oldFd = 0x5be1510: value = 22 = 0x16

-> ioGlobalStdSet(1, saveFd)

Answer (score 0):

The following code snippets show how to save all serial console output to a file.

Try -> tyco0_write_to_file 4096

```
#include <tyLib.h>
#include <private/iosLibP.h>

int tyco0_log_max_size = -1;
int tyco0_log_fd = -1;

int tyco0_write_hook(TY_DEV_ID pTyDev, char *buffer, int nbytes)
{
    FD_ENTRY *p_fd_entry;
    static int bytes_written = 0;

    if ('0' == pTyDev->devHdr.name[6]) { /* /tyCo/0 */
        if ((bytes_written+nbytes)<tyco0_log_max_size) {
            (void)write(tyco0_log_fd,buffer,nbytes);
            bytes_written += nbytes;
        }
        else {
            (void)write(tyco0_log_fd,buffer,tyco0_log_max_size-bytes_written);
            p_fd_entry = iosFdMap(1);
            p_fd_entry->pDrvEntry->de_write = tyWrite;
            close(tyco0_log_fd);
            bytes_written = 0;
        }
    }

    return tyWrite(pTyDev,buffer,nbytes);
}

int tyco0_write_to_file(int file_max_size)
{
    FD_ENTRY *p_fd_entry;

    p_fd_entry = iosFdMap(1); /*  /tyCo/0 */
    if (NULL==p_fd_entry) {
        perror("iosFdMap");
        return -1;
    }

    tyco0_log_fd = open("/ram/tyco0.log",O_CREAT|O_RDWR,0);
    if (tyco0_log_fd == -1) {
        perror("open");
        return -1;
    }

    if (file_max_size <= 0) {
        file_max_size = 1024;
    }
    tyco0_log_max_size = file_max_size;

    if (p_fd_entry->pDrvEntry->de_write == tyWrite) {
        p_fd_entry->pDrvEntry->de_write = tyco0_write_hook;
    }
    else {
        printf("tyWrite not found\n");
        close(tyco0_log_fd);
        return -1;
     }

    return 0;
}
```